# Finding X and Y axis line intercept points of a Circle - Python

Tags: python, math, geometry, line, zelle-graphics

Hey trying to learn how to code and I cant figure this exercise out.
Specifically getting the precise y axis intercept points.
The formula given works for getting the x axis points but I cant figure out how to get the y axis points.

Exercise :

Input : Radius of circle and the y - intercept of the line.

Output : Circle drawn with a horizontal line across the window with the given y intercept. Mark two points of the intersection.
Print the x values of the points of intersection *Formula : x = ± √r^2 - y^2

```
Code::

    from graphics import *
    from math import *

    def main():

    # enter radius and the y intercept of the line

    radius = eval(input("Put in radius:: "))
    yinter = eval(input("Put in y intersec:: "))

    #Draw window + circle + line 
    win = GraphWin()
    win.setCoords(-10.0, -10.0, 10.0, 10.0)
    circle = Circle(Point(0.0,0.0), radius)
    mcircle = Circle(Point(0.0,0.0), 0.5)
    circle.draw(win)
    mcircle.draw(win)

    line = Line(Point(-10, 0), Point(10, yinter))
    line.draw(win)

    #Calculate x axis points of intersept  
    xroot1 = sqrt(radius * radius - yinter * yinter)
    xroot2 = -abs(xroot1)
    print("Xroot 1 : ", xroot1)
    print("Xroot 2 : ", xroot2)

    x = 0
    yroot1 = sqrt(radius * radius - x * x)
    yroot2 = -abs(yroot1)
    print("Yroot 1 : ", yroot1)
    print("Yroot 2 : ", yroot2)

    #mark two points of intersept in red 
    sc1 = Circle(Point(xroot1, yroot1), 0.3)
    sc1.setFill('red')
    sc2 = Circle(Point(xroot2, yroot2), 0.3)
    sc2.setFill('red')
    sc1.draw(win)
    sc2.draw(win)

    main()

Answer - With Radius of 8 and Y intersect point of 2
Yroot1 = 7.75
Yroot2 = -7.75
Xroot1 = 8.0
Xroot2 = -8.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I just came up with a subroutine to find intersection points while solving another Zelle-graphics related SO question.  There may be ways to simplify the math but I'm going the long way around:

```
from graphics import *

def intersection(center, radius, p1, p2):

    """ find the two points where a secant intersects a circle """

    dx, dy = p2.x - p1.x, p2.y - p1.y

    a = dx**2 + dy**2
    b = 2 * (dx * (p1.x - center.x) + dy * (p1.y - center.y))
    c = (p1.x - center.x)**2 + (p1.y - center.y)**2 - radius**2

    discriminant = b**2 - 4 * a * c
    assert (discriminant > 0), 'Not a secant!'

    t1 = (-b + discriminant**0.5) / (2 * a)
    t2 = (-b - discriminant**0.5) / (2 * a)

    return Point(dx * t1 + p1.x, dy * t1 + p1.y), Point(dx * t2 + p1.x, dy * t2 + p1.y)

def main(win):
    center = Point(0.0, 0.0)

    # Enter radius

    radius = float(input("Put in radius: "))

    # Draw circle and center dot

    Circle(center, radius).draw(win)
    Circle(center, 0.3).draw(win)

    # Enter the y intercept of the line
    yinter = float(input("Put in y intercept: "))

    # Draw line

    p1, p2 = Point(-10.0, 0.0), Point(10.0, yinter)
    Line(p1, p2).draw(win)

    # Mark two points of intercept in red

    for i, root in enumerate(intersection(center, radius, p1, p2), start=1):
        print("Root {}:".format(i), root)
        dot = Circle(root, 0.3)
        dot.setFill('red')
        dot.draw(win)

win = GraphWin()
win.setCoords(-10.0, -10.0, 10.0, 10.0)

main(win)

win.getMouse()
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

**NOTE**

You can get values input that do not produce a secant, e.g. a radius of 2 and an intercept of 8.  Your code doesn't account for this -- the above will simply throw an assertion error if it occurs.  But you can upgrade that to an error you can catch and fix.

Answer (score 0):

For the y coordinates you can use a similar formula:

y = ± sqrt(r^2 - x^2)

and the do everything the same with marking the roots.

Comment: That is strange. Off in what direction? Does it happen for all points?

Comment: Ahh, I see. Im not familiar with drawing those points, but normally you should give an X and Y coordinate. The corresponding Y-coordinate of the xroot1 and xroot2 is ofcourse 0, not yroot1 or yroot2. The same goes for the other yroot points. There should be 4 points (or less, if the circle touches the axis instead of crosses) in the picture.

Answer (score 0):

You should write the code like this:

```
x = sqrt(r ** 2 - y ** 2)

line = Line(Point(-10, 0), Point(10, yinter))
line.draw(win)

Line(Point(-10,0) is wrong, it should read: 
Line(Point(-10,yinter).
```

Also set `Xroot1` and `Xroot2 = 0` or `-x=0, x=0`

Answer (score 0):

```
def intersection(center, radius, p1, p2):
  dx, dy = p2[0] - p1[0], p2[1] - p1[1]
  a = dx**2 + dy**2
  b = 2 * (dx * (p1[0]- center[0]) + dy * (p1[1] - center[1]))
  c = (p1[0] - center[0])**2 + (p1[1] - center[1])**2 - radius**2
  K = b**2 - 4 * a * c
  return True if K>0 else False  

if __name__ == "__main__":  
  p1 = 10,50
  p2 = 100,50
  center= 50,150
  radius = 600

print(intersection(center, radius, p1, p2))
```